# wpf button visibility in case of CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to make few buttons like this:

```
        <fluent:Button 
        Size="Middle"
        Visibility="{Binding Path=SomeTestingMethod}" 
        Command="{Binding Path=OtherMethod}" CommandParameter="PP" 
        Some Text</fluent:Button>
```

visible or not in case of "CommandParameter". I tried:

```
public Visibility SomeTestingMethod(object o)
{
    return o.ToString == "something" ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

But compiler do not even check it. Also tried stuff like this:

```
        private Visibility _someTestingMethod;
    public Visibility SomeTestingMethod
    {
        get  {
            var commandExecutor = new RelayCommand(ButtonVisibility);

            return _statusButtonsVisibility;
            }
    }

    public void ButtonVisibility(object o)
    {
        _statusButtonsVisibility =
                     o.ToString == "something" ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

"SomeTestingMethod" is then reached but "ButtonVisibility" not.
I Have found other ways to reach visibility, but none of them alows me to get CommandParameter.
How to do it correctly?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to bind the `Visibility` property to a method. That is not how it works. You can only bind properties to dependency properties or to a property of a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I don't think you have things hooked up correctly. You have `Visibility` bound to to `SomeTestingMethod`, the `CommandParameter` will be sent along with `OtherMethod`, not `SomeTestingMethod`.

Comment: The correct way to handle this would be to bind `Visibility` to a `bool` property (that triggers `INotifyPropertyChanged`), and use an `IValueConverter` on that binding to change the `bool` in to the correct `Visibility`.  That way, changing the `bool` property (possibly from the `Button` `Command`) will trigger the visibility change automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a few comments about the code presented.

First off, do you really want to make the button disappear if the user may not click it? I ask because the [`ICommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) interface has a `CanExecute()` method which can hold logic to determine if the command may be executed. When a button is bound to a **property** that is an instance of an object implementing the `ICommand` interface, the button will automatically enable/disable itself based on the results of the `CanExecute()` logic. Note, that if that logic does something on a different thread, you may have to force a re-query of the command availability.

If you truly want the button to disappear rather than being disabled, as mentioned by @Jason Boyd in the comments, this is best accomplished by binding the visibility to a Boolean **property** in the view model and using a [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) to show/hide the button based on true/false of the property.

The view model should implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface to communicate property changes to update the binding target.

Hopefully, that gives you a start in the right direction.

Comment: I tried to bind visibility to a property via BooleanToVisibilityConverter. I do not know how to hide some buttons and keep others using only ONE method at the start of the view. I need something to distinguish them. And I need them to disappear.

Comment: There must be something I'm missing. If you want to just hide some buttons, bind those buttons' Visibility property to the Boolean property while leave the other buttons' Visibility property unbound. Am I missing something?

Comment: Lets say I have 20 different buttons. When I'm opening my window I get some data that can make some buttons visible if they "match". I can't make 20 separate methods to do so, as certain

Comment: So the number of buttons visible to the user varies at runtime? If so, this may point to a different design. You could use whatever that data returns to dynamically create sub-view-models each of which represents a button for the user to click. Add those sub-view-models to an ObservableCollection and use a DataTemplate to display a button for each of those sub-view-models. Would that work?

Comment: You mean create buttons dynamically when window starts? Well, that seems to be prefect solution :)

Comment: Sounds like you need to research the "MVVM Pattern".  It can help you solve this.  It's a little tricky to learn if you aren't used to thinking about things that way though. It tends to turn things on their heads compared to how most programmers are used to thinking about things at first

Answer (score 0):

You can't get `CommandParameter` in property which you bind to Visibility property.

Get parameter in `OtherMethod` method and change `SomeTestingMethod` property.
Or you can use custom BoolToVisibility converter for using parametr.

Comment: So how can I pass something from particular buton to visibility? OtherMethod fires when I click on it, so a bit too late. I have found a lot of tutorials about setting visibility, but none of them could solve problem of getting something from xaml to viewModel. I can add something to xaml file.

Comment: You *can't* `Visibility` is the property you want to *change* to cause the control to hide.  For visibility, flow goes from Property->Control, not the other way around.